# Can Fabric display Yum or apt-get progress sliders correctly?

Tags: fabric

If you run

```
run('yum upgrade')
```

You'll see that the progress slider is repeated on screen, that is, every time it increments, a new line appears on screen unlike what you see in a 'real' ssh session (where the slider just increments to 100% on a single line).

Is there a way to make Fabric display this properly? I don't want to use -q because this silence all output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an example of curses at work. What version of Fabric are you on? Newer fabrics should handle this better. But anyhow you could also limit the output returned, yum has the -d flag for debug level, so you could get some info, but less.

Comment: Thanks Morgan, I'm on Fabric 1.6.1. -d 1 sorta works... I'll use it for now. Will close this question and assign you if there are no other answer in the next 10 days. Cheers!

Comment: 20 days later - can confirm I wasn't able to fix the problem short of Morgan's workaround. Don't think fabric is designed with this in mind.